# Django: Foreign Key Query to post the information on the html template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I'm stuck on my next step of showing the query from the database to the html template. I'm able to put some basic information, but I got stuck on the foreign key queries.

Here is sample of my code:

Here is my model:

```
class Player_Bios(models.Model):
    my_id            = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    player_id        = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, max_length=50)    
    name             = models.CharField(max_length=50) 
    last             = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __unicode__(self):
       return self.player_id

class BatStat (models.Model):
    player_id           = models.ForeignKey('Player_Bios')
    team_id             = models.ForeignKey('Team')
    bat_stat_id         = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    sport_code           = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True) 
    ab                  = models.IntegerField(max_length=50, null=True)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.bat_stat_id
```

My View:

```
def SpecificPLayer(request, playerslug):
   player = Player_Bios.objects.get(player_id=playerslug) #this is the name, last and it is working fine
   playerStat = BatStat.objects.filter(player_id=playerslug) #Here I'm calling the foreign key
   print playerStat
   context = {'player' : player, 'today' : date.today(), 'playerStat' : playerStat }
   return render_to_response ('singleplayer.html', context,          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

My HTML Template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}

  <div id="singleplayer">
       <p>Name: {{ player.name|capfirst  }}</p>
       <p>Last Name: {{ player.last|capfirst  }}</p>

  </div>
        {% endfor %}


{% endblock %}
```

Now when I do print playerStat, I get all of the BatStat from the player_id. In y case I get the following:

```
[<BatStat: 40539520011>, <BatStat: 40539520021>, <BatStat: 40539520031>]
```

I get the result that I want on the shell by doing the following:

```
playerStatID=BatStat.objects.filter(player_id='the player id here')
print playerStatID
[<BatStat: 40539520011>, <BatStat: 40539520021>, <BatStat: 40539520031>]
for i in playerStatID:
      playerStat= BatStat.objects.get(bat_stat_id=i)
      print BatStat.ab
      200
```

So by doing that I can get the information that I need it, now how can I get that, but to put it on the template. I can't use a loop on the template to get a query, so I guess the loop has to be done on the view, but how. Thanks

Comment: Every time i see this tag i think of the new Quentin Tarantino film .. +1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have a `ForeignKey` between `BatStat` and `Player_Bios`, you can use a `batstat_set` to get all related `BatStats` for the single player.

[Docs for `_set` here.][1]

So you would have your `views.py` as:

```
def SpecificPLayer(request, playerslug):
    player = Player_Bios.objects.get(player_id=playerslug) #this is the name, last and it is working fine   
    batstats = player.batstat_set.all() 
    context = {'player' : player, 'today' : date.today(), 'batstats': batstats, }
    return render_to_response ('singleplayer.html', context,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and in your template:

```
{% for stat in batstats %}
    {{ stat.ab }}
{% endfor %}
```